# How to show a Isbusy indication right when a window opens

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to show a visual indication "isbusy" while grids 1-3 are loading right when the window opens. I have been able to show the loading indication  after the grids have been loaded by using the "telerik:RadToggleButton isbusy" but i want to show it right when the window is opend and before the girds are loaded. can someone point me in the right direction thanks in advance.

```
 <Window.Resources/>

<UserControl Name="tbMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left">        
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <telerik:RadGridView (1)/>
                <telerik:RadGridView (2)/>
                <telerik:RadGridView (3)/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="SkyBlue">
            <Button x:Name="btnAcceptMerge" Content="Accept Merge" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnCancel"  Content="Cancel Merge" Click="btnCancel_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Text=""/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
 </Window>
```

Comment: I don't see a busy indicator control here ... are you using telerik's [BusyIndicator](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/busyindicator.aspx) control for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use busy control of Xceed toolkit . for using this you have to use backgroundworker.

below is complete solution.

XAML:

first you have to add namespace reference of  Xceed toolkit.

```
xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

after that you have to use BusyIndicator surround your grid also you can implement progress.

```
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" Background="#FFD1DEF0" >

                <TextBlock  Text="Generating......" />

                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                     <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ProgressValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType=Window}}" Height="15"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />

        </Style>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>

         <telerik:RadGridView (1)/>
            <telerik:RadGridView (2)/>
            <telerik:RadGridView (3)/>
 </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

in ViewModel:

in VM constructor you should set  IsVMBusy property true.

```
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
          {
    ///your task
     };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            IsVMBusy = false;
          };
         worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use telerik's BusyIndicator control to surround your grids, and bind it to a `IsBusy` property on your VM.

```
          <telerik:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
            <StackPanel>
               <telerik:RadGridView (1)/>
               <telerik:RadGridView (2)/>
               <telerik:RadGridView (3)/> 
            </StackPanel>
          </telerik:BusyIndicator/>
```

Assuming you use use a VM first technique, where the VM gets created before the view (I.e injecting it in the view's constuctor) you can set `IsBusy` to `True` in the VM's constructor and set it back to false when the grid's or done loading. Also make sure `IsBusy` raises `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: when i try this i get content can only be set once

Comment: @Robert my bad I wrote it down from memory, sorry. updated the answer